# MySQL or JSON view base on Node.js app and API

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I know this kind of question is ask in many different ways, and I know that's annoying for answering so much same question, but as I google it, search in Stackoverflow I can't really find a nice answer, the answer I'm asking is based on views like easy for answering API request (which is in JSON format) and in the view of I'm designing Node.js APP

---

#### So here is my case

I'm building my own Node.js application somehow like a CMS or blogging platform so imagine I need a place to store all my posts data where should I store in a `MySQL` database or `External JSON file` it's quite confusing I personally prefer JSON since it's nice looking (?) but it's quite hard to use `fs.writefile` and `fs.readfilesync` to update data in the external JSON, but I don't know how to make an API that will give the post data by MySQL database since the API is in the JSON format

---

If I have any misunderstood please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to store data in json then go form nosql database like mongodb. Postgresql latest versions also supports JSON data types.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting MongoDB, I've think about it but my base thought of designing the app is it can be use even in shared host environment and in my case my hosting environment of my website does not support MongoDB :(

Comment: then go for postgresql . Newer versions of it have json support. Also if mongodb is not supported then you can try for cassendra

Comment: oops, sorry I have contact my hosting provider and they announced that they only support postgresql and cassendra in VPS or dedicate server plan. Any suggestion that don't need root access are welcome

Comment: then go for cassendra or postgres

Comment: They said those two needs the root access to install it which is not supported in my case

Comment: so in that case u will be not able to use any database ? How you will going to install nodejs on server if you will not have root access ?

Comment: My environment only have node.js, MySQL and SQLite installed so it means you can only install node.js application i think like npm install, but you can't use any command that make global change such as `npm install -g package_name`

Comment: ohk in that case                                                                                    
 1) either you should purchase server that will allow you to install mongodb  OR                                                                                   2)you can write on application that will expose rest api in JSON format & that will listen & talk with your current application. OR                        3) you can use Google  firebase  databse (OPEN SOURCE)  OR          4) you can use Oracle MCS  databse (PAID)

Comment: I think fire base is a good option but does it support replying api request like a json array of the hello world post?

Comment: i think it supports.. You can check its documentation. Also kindly accept my answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving the suggestion of firebase but is there also a way to let MySQL reply the API though I prefer firebse (I really not prefer MySQL in PHP it's quite difficult to me)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is ORM module, for example [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)

It works with MySQL/Postgres, and offers you APIs like MongoDB.